# Rank of a Group by Function

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, group-by, rank

I have 3 tables 
SELECT * FROM BIS_RCNC_CRIT_ATTR

```
RCNC_CRIT_ATTR_ID   RCNC_CRIT_SET_ID    RCNC_ATTR_TYP_ID    RCNC_CRIT_ATTR_EXPR
60947   10660   5   5322
61039   10706   5   5322
75241   13077   5   5322
```

SELECT * FROM BIS_RCNC_ATTR_TYP

```
RCNC_ATTR_TYP_ID    RCNC_TYP_ID RCNC_ATTR_TYP_NM    RCNC_ATTR_TYP_DSC
1   1   SN  SN
2   1   CU  CU
3   1   IS  IS
4   1   SE  SE
5   1   IV  IV
6   1   BE  BE
7   1   PN  PN
8   1   PV  PV
```

SELECT * FROM BIS_RCNC_CRIT_SET

```
RCNC_CRIT_SET_ID    RCNC_CRIT_TYP_ID    RCNC_CRIT_SET_STAT
10660   2   A
10706   2   A
13077   2   A
```

I am running a query

```
select
    BIS_RCNC_CRIT_SET.RCNC_CRIT_SET_ID AS "ID",
    max(case when rcnc_attr_typ_nm ='IV' then rcnc_crit_attr_expr else null end) as "ACCT",
    max(case when rcnc_attr_typ_nm ='PN' then rcnc_crit_attr_expr else null end) as "Platform"
    FROM BIS_RCNC_CRIT_SET
INNER JOIN BIS_RCNC_CRIT_ATTR
    ON BIS_RCNC_CRIT_SET.RCNC_CRIT_SET_ID = BIS_RCNC_CRIT_ATTR.RCNC_CRIT_SET_ID
INNER JOIN BIS_RCNC_ATTR_TYP
    on bis_rcnc_crit_attr.rcnc_attr_typ_id = bis_rcnc_attr_typ.rcnc_attr_typ_id
where bis_rcnc_crit_set.rcnc_crit_typ_id = 2 and bis_rcnc_crit_set.RCNC_CRIT_SET_STAT = 'A'
group by
BIS_RCNC_CRIT_SET.RCNC_CRIT_SET_ID
```

The query is fetching duplicate value for IVAN and platform.

```
10706   5322        Bloomberg
10660   5322        Bloomberg
13077   5322        Bond Desk
```

How to eliminate duplicates based on platform and IVAN

What I want

```
10706   5322    Bloomberg   
13077   5322    Bond Desk
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data please?

Comment: Dude i am getting 3 rows ....for IVAN 5322 i am getting two bloomberg ...but i want only 1 that mean i want first and third row

Comment: But unless we know what the original data is like how can we know how to change the output?

Comment: @Rahul Chowdhury: Dude how can you expect someone to provide the solution when you are not providing them sufficient data to work on? Edit your question, put in the existing data sample and expected output and I will remove my downvote.

Comment: @Rachcha- Sorry for being late but i have tried my best to provide my details .Hope you will consider your DownVote :)

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood

```
select case when rcnc_attr_typ_nm ='Platform Name' then rcnc_crit_attr_expr else null end as "Platform",
       case when rcnc_attr_typ_nm ='IVAN' then rcnc_crit_attr_expr else null end as "ACCT",
       max(BIS_RCNC_CRIT_SET.RCNC_CRIT_SET_ID) AS "ID",
       max(case when rcnc_attr_typ_nm ='AcctName' then rcnc_crit_attr_expr else null end)as "AcctName"
  FROM BIS_RCNC_CRIT_SET INNER JOIN BIS_RCNC_CRIT_ATTR
                         ON BIS_RCNC_CRIT_SET.RCNC_CRIT_SET_ID = BIS_RCNC_CRIT_ATTR.RCNC_CRIT_SET_ID
                         INNER JOIN BIS_RCNC_ATTR_TYP
                         on bis_rcnc_crit_attr.rcnc_attr_typ_id = bis_rcnc_attr_typ.rcnc_attr_typ_id
 where bis_rcnc_crit_set.rcnc_crit_typ_id = 2 and bis_rcnc_crit_set.RCNC_CRIT_SET_STAT = 'A'
 group by case when rcnc_attr_typ_nm ='Platform Name' then rcnc_crit_attr_expr else null end
     , case when rcnc_attr_typ_nm ='IVAN' then rcnc_crit_attr_expr else null end
```

Please check if this is what you wanted.

Best regards

Comment: I have modified my question and provided more details .Can you please have a try on the same . Above solution is not working for me .

Comment: Sorry for not replying but it's easy, just group by Platform the logic will be similar